# 3 tier SP Services Cascading Dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices, newform, cascading-dropdown

I have 4 lists:

1. Category
2. Subcategory
3. Detail
4. IT Service Request

**Column Details**:

1. Category list has one column: "Title"
2. Subcategory list has two columns: "Title" and a lookup column named "Category"
3. Detail list has two columns: "Title" and a lookup column named "Subcategory".
4. IT Service Request list has multiple columns: Assigned On/Assigned To/Requester name, etc.

Here is my script:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
relationshipList: "Subcategory",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Category",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Category",
    childColumn: "Subcategory",
    debug: true
})
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "Detail", 
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Subcategory", 
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Subcategory",
    childColumn: "Detail",
    debug: true
})
```

In my "IT Service Request" list, I added it into the source in a content editor in Newform.aspx. At first, this worked just fine. But something happened and all of a sudden it's not working at all. I tested JQuery and it *is* loading. But my cascading dropdown isn't working whatsoever.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what's wrong. Help!

I'm using SharePoint Enterprise 2016. Thank you!

Comment: If that is the exact code, you have a syntax error in loading your SPServices.  Also, you should save the JS file locally instead of doing an external call to them.

Comment: Yeah, I just haven't gotten there yet. It's on Dev so I'm just trying to make sure I can get it to work first and foremost. What's the syntax error?

Comment: I noticed what you're saying. The script that I put in was actually correct and didn't have the extra > in the beginning. Still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

The "https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js" is not exists.

Modify the code as below to make it works.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Subcategory",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Category",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Category",
        childColumn: "Subcategory",
        debug: true
    });
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Detail", 
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Subcategory", 
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Subcategory",
        childColumn: "Detail",
        debug: true
    });
})
</script>
```

[image]

I suggest you download the **jquery-1.10.1.min.js** and **jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js** files and upload it to Site Assets library, then reference the files from the library.

Comment: I updated the script. Then, I did update to site assets library and referenced from the library. No dice for both. I've cleared cache, too. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The reference like below: 
<script src="/sites/team/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sites/team/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Correct. It's exactly the same. I've also tried using this on other sites I've created and none of them at working correctly.

Comment: Try to use the Full URL of the file, like : http://abc/sites/team/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.1.min.js.

Comment: Tried, also didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to use reference below?
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Correct, still didn't work.

Comment: Check if the list name and column internal name are right.

Comment: Everything is correct. Still not working.